# Change the date format before appending with string builder

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a grid with eight columns and `n` number of rows in which two columns are dates with the format `dd-mmm-yyyy` (e.g. `18 oct 2017`). Now I need to append this all data and write to a text file but before appending I have to convert the date format to `yyyymmdd` (e.g. `20171018`).

Answer (score 3):

[StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) has a special [AppendFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat) method for formatting. It uses the [composite formatting feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting). So the code may look like this:

```
var sourceDate = DateTime.Now;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("{0:yyyyMMdd}", sourceDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple, assume you have a variable with date

```
var sourceDate=DateTime.Now;
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
myString.Append(sourceDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")); //This will do the job.
```

You can loop through each Rows, take the date value from the respective columns to a date variable, sourceDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") (here sourceDate is the date variable) will give you the formatted output format.